# How to load JSON response with codable structure into tableview using Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

My scenario, I am trying to create `Codable` for my `JSON` response. I have done `codable` structure but I don’t know how to `load` it into `tableview`. Here, whenever I am selecting multiple `tableview` cell I need to get all selected cell data `username` and userid. I don’t know how to start please provide me some suggestion.

My Response

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "user_list": [
        {
            "user_id": “1234”,
            "permission": 1,
            "active": 1,
            "user": {
                "firstname": “jack”,
                "lastname": “m”
            }
        },etc,...
        ]
}
```

My codable formate

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let userList: [UserList]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case userList = "user_list"
    }
}

struct UserList: Codable {
    let userID: String
    let permission, active: Int
    let user: User

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userID = "user_id"
        case permission, active, user
    }
}

struct User: Codable {
    let firstname, lastname: String
}
```

Comment: Can you put some code of your `tableview`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would rename your `UserList` model to `User` and `User` just to `Name` (and rename this property just to name ... then you can rename `Name`'s properties)

```
struct Welcome: Codable { // you can avoid using `CodingKeys` here since you can
    let status: Int       // set `keyDecodingStrategy` of decoder which does work 
    let userList: [User]  // for you
}

struct User: Codable {
    let userId: String
    let permission, active: Int
    let name: Name

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "user"
        case permission, active, userId
    }
}

struct Name: Codable {
    let first, last: String
}
```

---

Then I think in your case your data source array for `UITableView` should contains just users, so... your `User` models.

```
var users = [User]()
```

then you can assign this array as your decoded response's `userList` property

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let decoded = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: someData)
    self.users = decoded.userList
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Now, for `UITableView` data source method which determine number of rows use count of users

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return users.count
}
```

and for `cellForRowAt` use certain user

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    // e.g. let firstname = user.name.first
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dresler Could you please add me one more how to get status code also.

Comment: @devmikle I don't know what you mean, but check edited answer

Comment: Thank you. I will try my side and update you here :)@Robert Dresler

Comment: getting keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "userList", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"userList\", intValue: nil) (\"userList\").", underlyingError: nil)) @Robert Dresler

Comment: @devmikle have you set `keyDecodingStrategy` of decoder?

Answer (score 0):

Your API call should return a Data object. To parse it you can use:

```
 func parseWelcome(dataFromServer:Data,handlerDone: @escaping (_ welcome:Welcome) ->Void) ->Void {
    do {
        let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from:jsonData!)
        handlerDone(welcome)
    } catch {

        // A handler could be defined here for handeling bad response from server
        print("API:An error occurred while parsing server response Welcome")
    }
}
```

Call the function and pass your rawData from the server. I conclude you have a User array somewhere, so let's populate it

```
parseWelcome(dataFromServer: rawData!) { parsedData in

   // Users should be an Array of Users defined by you somewhere
   users = parsedData.userList
}
```

Call the tableView and load the data from your users array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "notes", for: indexPath)

        // Construct your cell on your needs use users[indexPath.row]
        ...
}
```

But I agree with @Robert Dresler that you have a bad Model design. It is recommended to redesign it a little bit.