# Need Help Parsing Nested JSON Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, urlsession

I need help parsing this JSON

```
{
  "products_and_categories" : {
    "new" : [
      {
        "id" : 173577,
        "image_url" : "\/\/assets.supremenewyork.com\/193786\/ca\/tMUMOnomKJI.jpg",
        "name" : "Penguins Hooded Fleece Jacket",
        "price" : 19800,
        "sale_price" : 0,
        "image_url_hi" : "\/\/assets.supremenewyork.com\/193786\/rc\/tMUMOnomKJI.jpg",
        "new_item" : true,
        "position" : 4,
        "category_name" : "Jackets"
      },
      {
        "id" : 173581,
        "image_url" : "\/\/assets.supremenewyork.com\/193727\/ca\/ywdDy1mQ51Q.jpg",
        "name" : "Side Logo Track Jacket ",
        "price" : 15800,
        "sale_price" : 0,
        "image_url_hi" : "\/\/assets.supremenewyork.com\/193727\/rc\/ywdDy1mQ51Q.jpg",
        "new_item" : true,
        "position" : 3,
        "category_name" : "Jackets"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have made this struct for saving the values that are parsed

```
var modelsArray: [Products] = Array() //is Products the right one for the array?

struct Products: Codable {
    let products: Categories

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case products = "products_and_categories"
    }
}

struct Categories: Codable {
    let new: [New]
}

struct New: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let price: Int
    let category: String
    let image: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name, price
        case category = "category_name"
        case image = "image_url_hi"
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop.json")!
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
   if data = data {
// Having trouble with what to put here to append id, name, price, category, image for tableview
   }


}.resume()
```

But now i'm stuck, i am having trouble converting this into the request to append the data i need. Essentially i want to be able to put id, name, price, category, image into a tableview cell

Comment: You'd need to decode a `Products` type: `let products = try JSONDecoder(Products.self, from: data)`. Then you'd access the inner array with: `let arrOfNew = products.products.new`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load JSON response with codable structure into tableview using Swift 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769299/how-to-load-json-response-with-codable-structure-into-tableview-using-swift-4-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I might assume, you must be using the `new` `array` to load the data in your `tableView`. So, you need to define your `modelsArray` like,

```
var modelsArray: [New] = Array()
```

Then parse the JSON `data` like so,

```
session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Products.self, from: data)
            modelsArray = response.products.new
            //reload your tableView here...
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: This is an async call. So, printing after resume() will give you empty array because till that time you haven’t received the data. Also, call tableView.reloadData() inside DispatchQueue.main.async.